# Setting Font Attributes Using Python-Docx

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, lxml, python-docx

I am creating a word document programmatically using the [Python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) module.

I want to be able to **center my headers**, turn certain **words to bold** in a table I create, and do **other basic mark up**.

Unfortunately, reading over the source code in the module doesn't give me much of a lead on doing this.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the lxml/etree module that the docx code is based upon, but I don't have much familiarity with that library. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The link above points to the legacy repository for python-docx. The new one (v0.3.0 and later) is a complete rewrite and is located here: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx

All the features listed above are available in the current version.

The documentation is here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Only bug fixes are being done on the legacy version, to support projects that still use it.

The `python-docx` SO tag is monitored and questions tagged with that usually get answered same day now.